# GeoJSON and HTML/JavaScript vs Shapefile and Silverlight

Tags: shapefile, geojson, silverlight

I'm developing a map application (Several shapefiles with OpenstreetMap or BingMap on background and some dynamically generated features on the map). I'vs created some part of it with Telerik RadMap for silverlight. but I'm far more comfortable with Javascript and HTML (I'm mainly a web developer).

So, is there any advises on how to choose the right technologies for a web based map application? is there Any shortcomings for Javascript components that support GeoJSON (leafletjs, KendoMap, ...)? Any comparisons between `GeoJSON and HTML/JavaScript vs Shapefile and Silverlight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTML5 announcement flash support has dropped, and adobe has ditched flex, and now [they predict that (flash, silverlight, java) will die](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-web-predictions-2014/)

so for the moment the future is for HTML5 and JS.

Comment: You are right but silverlight is a great technology and is going to be used for a long time ([Microsoft Silverlight is Dead; Long Live Silverlight!](http://techventuregeek.com/software-reviews/microsoft-silverlight-is-dead-long-live-silverlight/#.U_m8QPmSzpw)). I wanna know is there anyone who had experience with both.

Comment: I'm now using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and I'm so happy with the results. It's way more better than silverlight. Thanks for your answer.